# Python - openpyxl read xlsx data after writing on existing xlsx with formula

Tags: python, xlsx, openpyxl, read-write

I am trying to read a xlsx file after writing on the existing xlsx excel file using **openpyxl**.

My Excel file `file1.xlsx` having value `1` on `A1`, value `2` on `A2` and value `A1 + A2` on `A3`, which is `3` at this point.

```
def updateFile(a):
    wb = load_workbook('file1.xlsx')
    ws = wb.active
    #Update specific column
    ws['A1'] = a
    wb.save('file1.xlsx')

def readFile():
    wb = load_workbook('file1.xlsx')
    sheet = wb['Sheet1']
    print(sheet['A3'].value)
```

My program is going to update `A1` on `file1.xlsx` and read the data on `A3`. For example, calling `updateFile(5)` will update `A1` to `5`, and perhaps giving me `7` on `A3`.

Unfortunately, after `updateFile(5)` is called, `readFile()` will gives `= A1 + A2` as output, instead of `7`.

This is mainly because the data on Excel file is updated but not saved. And if I want to let `readFile()` to output `7`, I have to open `file1.xlsx` manually, Save it, and Close it.

Are there anyway or am I misusing read/write on openpyxl to resolve this issues? I believe I had not Save the file properly or I have to figure a way to open, save, close an Excel file programmatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are seeing is expected behaviour. When cells have formulae then Excel saves the result of the formula as a cached value. openpyxl never evaluates formulae so never maintains a cache and invalidates any existing cache. Instead, if you want the results of a formula then you can load the file with the `data_only=True` parameter. Though this will replace the formula with the value.

This is covered in the documentation: http://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/stable/usage.html#read-an-existing-workbook

Comment: Hi Charlie, for your information, I tried to use data_only=True when referring to the documentation provided. However, after updateFile(5) is called, A3 became "None" when readFile() is called with wb = load_workbook('file1.xlsx',data_only=True). As said on the post, this can only be fixed after I had actually open the Excel file and Save it when close it.

Comment: This is expected behaviour: the existing cache is invalidated by openpyxl. Before you edit the file the result might be cached as `7`. Once you save it in openpyxl there is no cache so opening in `data_only` mode will return `None` for every calculation. To avoid this you must edit in `data_only` mode but this missing losing the formulae. Otherwise pipe the file through something like a headless version of OpenOffice Calc to get the cache recalculated.

Comment: So I assume there is no way for me to read the updated cell on 'A3' after writing the data using 'updateFile(5)'. As editing in 'data_only' mode will cause 'A3' losing the formulae and perhaps the data in 'A3' will not update as well.

Comment: If you want to edit a worksheet with formulae in it and keep the formulae, then the results of those formulae will not be available. Imagine you have a cell with the formula `=A1+A2` there is no way to know whether the previously cached value is still correct. Therefore it must be invalidated and recalculated. As openpyxl does not evaluate formulae you will need to use another application to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. My approach is the following:

```
print('Reopen all files and save again')
for eachFile in glob.glob(path + fileCriteria)[:]:
    xl = DispatchEx('Excel.Application')
    xl.Visible = False
    wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(eachFile)
    wb.Close(True)
```