# Pandas read_excel returning nan for cells having simple formula if excel file is created by program

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

I use `pd.read_excel` to read a excel file which is created by `openpyxl` and downloaded from a url.

The parsed dataframe will give `nan` if the cell value is a formula.

```
# which formula is simply =100-3
       0
0    NaN
```

I try to open it manually with MS Office, click "edit" button, and save it, the problem is solved.

```
# after saving the excel, problem is solved, e.g. 97
       0
0     97
```

I want to know is there a solution that do it programmatically? and if without using MS Excel or win32com will be great. Thanks

Comment: @mozway Thanks for point that out. I think that post can answer my half question, it's need manually open excel file with MS Excel and save it. what I need is do it automatically (solutions without MS Excel, win32com installed are better.)

Comment: Could you provide an example file?

Comment: @mozway Sure, [from my NAS share](https://ku88.xyz/drive/d/f/629839667719615474)

Comment: And I also comment to a [closed pandas issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/25763)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

not enough points  to comment but this probably can help you:

[stackoverflowanswer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59837519/pandas-read-excel-returning-nan-for-cells-having-formula)

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I think some solutions there were suit for different kind of situation.

Answer (score 2):

After doing some searches, I found my question may be duplicated with (or similar to):

- [pandas-read-excel-returning-nan-for-cells-having-formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59837519/pandas-read-excel-returning-nan-for-cells-having-formula)

and found more explanations from:

- [python-openpyxl-read-xlsx-data-after-writing-on-existing-xlsx-with-formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33008610/python-openpyxl-read-xlsx-data-after-writing-on-existing-xlsx-with-formula)
- [openpyxl-data-only-gives-only-a-none-answer-when-storing-a-variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31444905/openpyxl-data-only-gives-only-a-none-answer-when-storing-a-variable)
- [python-openpyxl-data-only-true-returning-none](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36116162/python-openpyxl-data-only-true-returning-none)
- [refresh-excel-external-data-with-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40893870/refresh-excel-external-data-with-python)

Some notes (conclusions):

- `openpyxl` can write but **doesn't** caculate the excel formula, it just read cached value from last calculation by MS excel or other applications if possible with `data_only=True` arguments.
- for solving this manually, like @Orlando's answer mentioned, open excel apps and save it (will automatically calculate/produce the formula results)
- for solving this programatically (with excel app installed), you just use `win32com` open and save it. (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56434787/3214422))
- for solving this programatically (without excel app), you must calculate the results from excel formula string by yourself or some module like [formulas](https://github.com/vinci1it2000/formulas), then set the caculated value back to cell (**Warning**: this will delete the formula) . If you also want to keep formula with default/cached value, you should use [XlsxWriter](https://github.com/jmcnamara/XlsxWriter) which can write formula in cell with a default/cached value.

For me, because my formula is very simple, I use `eval` like:

```
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('./test_formula2.xlsx')
ws = wb.active
ws.cell(2,2).value # '=100-1'
eval(ws.cell(2,2).value[1:]) # slice after '=', e.g. 99
```

to get the calculated result.

Comment: You have to be very careful when using exec, especially when using downloaded files. With your method, it is quite easy to craft files to execute arbitrary code. For instance, using the following text in a cell that would be executed " open('/tmp/malicious_file.txt', 'w').write('malicious code')" one can create an arbitrary file.

Comment: @mozway Thanks for the notice, Althoug the excel file is created by my NAS app which can be trusted, I should more carefully use `eval` to run the arbitrary formula.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [formulas](https://pypi.org/project/formulas/)

The following snippet seems to work:

```
import formulas
xl_model = formulas.ExcelModel().loads('test_formula.xlsx').finish()
xl_model.calculate()
xl_model.write(dirpath='.')
```

This will write a "TEST_FORMULA.XLSX" (all caps for some reason) file with calculated values in place of the formulas. Importantly, this does not rely on Excel.

Here is the [formulas documentation](https://formulas.readthedocs.io/en/stable/doc.html) if you need to dig into it.

Comment: As the solutions I mentioned from my answer, and you just give a great example! Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, I did not read all the provided links. A direct example is better to see for future users.