# Pandas reading excel file w/ or w/out formulas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xlrd

I am reading an excel file with pandas using xlrd(1.2.0). The excel file I am reading has formulas all over the sheet.

What I was wondering is when reading a sheet via `pd.read_excel(...)`, does it just copy the values, that I can see in excel (even though under the values there is the excel formulas),

or

when reading it, pandas recalculates the formulas like excel, and then gets the values?

if an image version of the excel sheet, which consist only values, would speed up the reading process of pandas?

**Test Case:** Basically `'cost-comparison-value.xlsx'` is the only-value version of `'cost-comparison.xlsx'`.

```
import time
import pandas as pd

start = time.time()
formula = pd.read_excel('cost-comparison.xlsx', sheet_name='results')
print(time.time() - start)

start = time.time()
value = pd.read_excel('cost-comparison-value.xlsx', sheet_name='results')
print(time.time() - start)
```

**Output:**

```
0.5445430278778076
0.23437285423278809
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas read\_excel returning nan for cells having simple formula if excel file is created by program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68279849/pandas-read-excel-returning-nan-for-cells-having-simple-formula-if-excel-file-is)

Comment: pandas won't do any calculation on formulas. It will instead consider all cells with formulas as NaN. It would definitely be better to export a values-only spreadsheet. Alternatively, to perform formula calculations, see the link above.

Comment: It definitly gathers the values somehow using formulas, because there arent any nan values in my pandas df...